# Talend DI Component to visit URL

Tags: talend

Is there any component in **Talend Open Studio for Data Integration** to **visit URL** and records the timings, or perform some activities, etc.

Comment: Word "visit" is not so technical, can you please be more specefic ?

Comment: Is any component in Talend DI which opens specified url internally inside talend or browser and records the activites

Answer (score 0):

You can use [tHttpRequest](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tHttpRequest) to send http request to server, and to get timing use [tChronometerStart](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendOpenStudioforBigDataComponentsReferenceGuide60EN/tChronometerStart) and [tChronometerStop](https://help.talend.com/display/TalendComponentsReferenceGuide61EN/tChronometerStop).

Comment: Please consider below sample case to understand my requirement -

1. Open http://google.co.in/ in specific talend component or browser
2. Enter "Hello" in search box
3. Opens first google suggested link in new tab

Please suggest any other tool to do this which I can integrate with my existing talend job.